# Cannot install pattern module in python on windows ubuntu

Tags: python, mysql, database, installation, mariadb

I am trying to import a python module called pattern in my code. However, when I run:
`pip install pattern`

I get the following output:

`Collecting pattern
Using cached 
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/07/b0e61b6c818ed4b6145fe01d1c341223aa6cfbc3928538ad1f2b890924a3/Pattern-3.6.0.tar.gz
Collecting future (from pattern)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/52/e20466b85000a181e1e144fd8305caf2cf475e2f9674e797b222f8105f5f/future-0.17.1.tar.gz
Collecting backports.csv (from pattern)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/26/a6bd68f13e0f38fbb643d6e497fc3462be83a0b6c4d43425c78bb51a7291/backports.csv-1.0.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mysqlclient (from pattern)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4d/38/c5f8bac9c50f3042c8f05615f84206f77f03db79781db841898fde1bb284/mysqlclient-1.4.4.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4Proy9/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4Proy9/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-4Proy9/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (12 lines):
    sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
    sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-4Proy9/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 16, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 61, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 29, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (_mysql_config_path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`

I already have mysql installed and I've tried installing mysqlclient as well. I am not sure what to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build/install mysqlclient you will need mysqlclient libraries and header files. To determine their location mysqlclient needs to call mysql_config script (which was not found).

You need to install mysql client library. (e.g. libmysqlclient-dev). Also make sure that mysql_config script is in your path.